# AttributeError: type object 'Point' has no attribute 'orientation'

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi, python-packaging

AttributeError: type object 'Point' has no attribute 'orientation' in Python Package

**Package Structure**

```
Graph/ 
 └── src/
    └── Graph/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── point.py
```

**point.py**

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __str__(self):
        return '('+str(self.x)+' , ' + str(self.y)+')'
    @classmethod 
    def orientation(cls, p, q, r):
        val = (float(q.y - p.y) * float(r.x - q.x)) - (float(q.x - p.x) * float(r.y - q.y))
        if (val > 0):
            return 1
        elif (val < 0):
            return 2
        else:
            return 0
```

**_ *init* _.py**

```py
from .point import *
```

```py
from Graph import Point
p1 = Point(1,1)
p2 = Point(2,2)
p3 = Point(3,2)
print(Point.orientation(p1,p2,p3))
```

**AttributeError: type object 'Point' has no attribute 'orientation'**

Comment: Running your code doesn't give me that error.

Comment: What is the purpose of making it `classmethod`, if you don't use it at all? You are looking for the `staticmethod` decorator. The `classmethod` is useful when you want an alternative constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `staticmethod` seems to work fine

```
from __future__ import annotations


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return '(' + str(self.x) + ' , ' + str(self.y) + ')'

    @staticmethod
    def orientation(p: Point, q: Point, r: Point) -> int:
        val = (float(q.y - p.y) * float(r.x - q.x)) - (float(q.x - p.x) * float(r.y - q.y))
        if val > 0:
            return 1
        elif val < 0:
            return 2
        else:
            return 0


p1 = Point(1, 1)
p2 = Point(2, 2)
p3 = Point(3, 2)
print(Point.orientation(p1, p2, p3))
```

Comment: What is the impact of the editing on my solution?

Comment: orientation() missing 1 required positional argument: 'r'

Comment: did you copy & paste my code and tested it? As far as I know - there is no such error.